# zf2 append to existing column content

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to use the CONCAT feature of mysql, using zf2 (Zend Framework).

How do I append to an existing text column value?

Example

old value: image1Path
new value: image1Path**image2path.

My function in the model table file.

```
public function updatePresImages($orderId,$newImageName)
{   
    $data = array(
        'prescription_upload_path'      => ??, 
        'date_updated'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
    $updateStatus=$this->tableGateway->update($data, array('user_medicine_order_id' => $orderId));
    return  $updateStatus;          
}
```

Comment: I assume you are using SQL. Are you performing the select query? What are column names?

Comment: No, not direct sql , i am looking for query using zend gramework2.Update same column appending to exsting content

Comment: You should post some code. Need to see how you are dealing with database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can see that your using `TableGatway`. Maybe you could try this :

```
public function updatePresImages($orderId,$newImageName)
{   
    $sql = "UPDATE yourTable SET prescription_upload_path= CONCAT(prescription_upload_path, '##', '$newImageName'), date_updated=now() WHERE user_medicine_order_id= '$orderId'"
    $updateStatus=$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);

    return  $updateStatus;          
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Table gateway way to achieve the require update is using Zend Expression.

Include following use statement at Top of your model class

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
```

Then

```
$this->tableGateway->update(array(
        'prescription_upload_path' => new Expression('CONCAT(prescription_upload_path, "##", "'.$newImageName.'")'),
        'date_updated' => new Expression('now()')
    ),
    array(
        'user_medicine_order_id' => $orderId,

    )
);
```

Comment: ,thanks , this is even more appropriate answer, but i have already accepted previous answer , i got it right in time for me....

Comment: sorry for late reply, i do not have enough reputation to upvote !